# give element class when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I would like to give an element a .class when user scrolls a page. And then take it away (.class) when user stops scrolling.

Simply speaking, I want to give font awesome icon class fa-spin only when page is being scrolled, and when scrolling stops, icon stops spinning.

Would be nice to know how to just generally apply css animation when scrolling.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/ssorallen/jquery-scrollstop

```
var $el = $('.element');
$(window).on("scrollstart", function() {
   $el.addClass('scrolling')
})
$(window).on("scrollstop", function() {
   $el.removeClass('scrolling')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addClass` and `removeClass` on `scroll` event as follow.
This will add class when scrolling and remove it after delay of 100 milliseconds.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('div').addClass('myClass');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('div').removeClass('myClass');
    }, 100);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/q9d787x1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('div').addClass('blue');//add class on scroll
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        $('div').removeClass('blue');//remove class on scrolling stops
    }, 250));
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3guvs1vd/)

Answer (score 0):

To add e.g. fadeIn animation on scroll you can do as following:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
$('#second').delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
```

(delay is optional)

Check example: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/AgilePlayers/q9d787x1/14/)